# AWS Glacier multipart upload fails: "The upload ID was not found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, upload, archive, multipart, amazon-glacier

I have succesfully created the first vault and uploaded files to it.

After this, I succesfully created a second vault, sent the `initiate-multipart-upload` checked it's existence with `list-multipart-uploads` that returned the `MultipartUploadId`-s correctly.

```
aws glacier list-multipart-uploads  --account-id 987654321 --vault-name secondvault
```

Using the exact same method that I used before, I am trying to issue `upload-multipart-part` commands without success:

```
$ aws glacier upload-multipart-part --upload-id XXXXXXX --body "path_to_file.tar.gz.gpg" --range 'bytes 0-536870911/*' --account-id 987654321 --vault-name secondvault

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the UploadMultipartPart operation: The upload ID was not found: XXXXXXX
```

What am I doing wrong? Why cannot I upload anything? It sais that the `The upload ID was not found` but `list-multipart-uploads` confirms its existence.